# Bring bullet to front on hover

Tags: amcharts

I have two series where the bullets overlap (XY scatter chart), each series only has one bullet, I would like the bullet that is hovered on to be shown on top of the other.

I'm trying the following code, which sits inside the a create series function, it seems to set the zIndex, but doesn't have the desired effect. Any suggestions on the best way to approach this? I've tried creating a hover state, but also didn't succeed.

```
bullet.events.on("over", function (event) {
    event.target.zIndex = 10;
})

bullet.events.on("out", function (event) {
    event.target.zIndex = 1;
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
bullet.events.on("over", function () {
    series.bulletsContainer.zIndex = 2;
})

bullet.events.on("out", function () {
    series.bulletsContainer.zIndex = 1;
})
```